# How can I add a directory to the Perl library path at the system level?

Tags: linux, perl, path, include

On a standard linux set up, where can I add a directory to the `@INC` variable?

In the `/etc/profile` file, I added:

```
 export PERLLIB=$PERLLIB:/foo/bar
 export PERL5LIB=$PERL5LIB:/foo/bar
```

Thanks

Comment: You just answered your own question. What are you looking for other than that?

Comment: You only need to do  PERL5LIB - PERLLIB is a fallback should PERL5LIB not be defined (and defining both IMHO causes confusion)

Comment: [Want to know how @INC is constructed?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2526809/150371)

Answer (score 2):

If you want every Perl script to have the additional library paths, you can re-compile Perl and specify the extra directories as part of the setup. Other than that, you're stuck with the ad hoc methods as you describe.

Comment: Rebuilding Perl sounds a bit of an overkill just to get an extra library in @INC

Comment: You only need to rebuild it if you want it to be there without having to do anything else. Otherwise, just use PERL5LIB.

Answer (score 2):

You might also need to source your ~/.bashrc so that it rebuilds your environment, or log out and log back in, before this change takes effect.  At least this would be required if you made that change in your local ~/.bash_profile instead of system wide.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to PERL5LIB through /etc/profile, or a script inside of /etc/profile.d only works if your program is run from the command line.  If you call it elsewhere, such as from a crontab entry, that will not work.  What I do is add a line at the top of the program, under use strict, but before all other uses that looks like this:

```
push @INC, '/foo/bar' unless grep('/foo/bar', @INC);
```