# How is Perl's @INC constructed?

Tags: perl, perl-module

What are all the ways of affecting where Perl modules are searched for?
or, How is Perl's @INC constructed?

As we know, [Perl uses `@INC` array containing directory names to determine where to search for Perl module files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526520/how-does-a-perl-program-know-where-to-find-the-file-containing-perl-module-it-use).

There does not seem to be a comprehensive `@INC` FAQ-type post on StackOverflow, so this question is intended as one.

Comment: Yeah, but there's a perfectly good one at http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfaq8#How_do_I_add_a_directory_to_my_include_path_(@INC)_at_runtime?

Comment: @mobrule: I don't think that's anywhere near as comprehensive - it's just telling how to add to `@INC` at runtime, not the full construction.

Comment: @mobrule - @Jefromi guessed right - the main problem with ANY and all references I found so far was a lack of comprehensive info on perl binary's compiled-in default @INC

Comment: Some can make that answer as comprehensive by sending me a patch. It's easy because perlfaq is in Github. :)

Comment: Well, the "comprehensive info on perl binary's compiled-in default @INC" is that it's the one the person who compiled it set up. If your asking about the various paths that get in there, then I think you have a different question than the one you answered.

Comment: @brian - If you feel the question is inappropriate for SO, you have enough rep points to moderate it out of existence. I will understand your reasons due to the comments above and will not contest that (hey! I got killed by the best sword in the Empire!), although I happen to disagree.

Comment: Also, my rep points mean nothing in terms of moderation. I don't really have any more power to do anything that anyone else who can edit.

Comment: Don't 10k give you full mod powers, including deletion? I had them way too briefly (1 week or so before the Great Recalc) to find out what was in scope :)

Comment: No, 10k lets you see deleted posts. The only moderators are the ones with the diamonds next to their names.

Comment: If you just want to see your @INC and you have GNU grep, this is a convenient command: `perl -V | grep -A20 '@INC'`  (20 lines after the @INC heading should be more than enough, but you can season to taste)

Answer (score 273, accepted):

We will look at how the contents of this array are constructed and can be manipulated to affect where the Perl interpreter will find module files.

1. Default `@INC`

The Perl interpreter is [compiled with a specific default value for `@INC`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/INSTALL). To find this value, run the command `env -i perl -V` (`env -i` ignores the `PERL5LIB` environment variable - see #2) and in the output you will see something like this:

> ```
> $ env -i perl -V
> ...
> @INC:
>  /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld
>  /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.0
>  /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld
>  /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.0
>  .
> ```

Note the `.` at the end; this is the current directory (which is not necessarily the same as the script's directory). It is missing in Perl 5.26+, and when Perl runs with [`-T` (taint checks enabled)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-T*).

To change the default path when configuring compilation of the Perl binary, set the configuration option [`otherlibdirs`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?INSTALL#otherlibdirs):

> `Configure -Dotherlibdirs=/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16.3`

2. Environment variable `PERL5LIB` (or `PERLLIB`)

Perl prepends a list of directories (colon-separated) contained in the `PERL5LIB` environment variable of your shell to `@INC` (if `PERL5LIB` is not defined, `PERLLIB` is used). To see the contents of `@INC` after the `PERL5LIB` and `PERLLIB` environment variables have taken effect, run `perl -V`:

> ```
> $ perl -V
> ...
> %ENV:
>   PERL5LIB="/home/myuser/test"
> @INC:
>  /home/myuser/test
>  /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld
>  /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.18.0
>  /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi-ld
>  /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.0
>  .
> ```

3. `-I`  command-line option

Perl prepends a list of directories (colon-separated) passed as the parameter of the `-I` command-line option to `@INC`. This can be done in three ways, as usual with Perl options:

- Pass it on command line:

  ```
      perl -I /my/moduledir your_script.pl
  ```
- Pass it via the first line (shebang) of your Perl script:

  ```
      #!/usr/local/bin/perl -w -I /my/moduledir
  ```
- Pass it as part of the `PERL5OPT` (or `PERLOPT`) environment variable (see chapter 19.02 in [Programming Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004927))

4. Pass it via the [`lib` pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html)

Perl prepends a list of directories passed in to it via `use lib` to `@INC`.

In a program:

```
    use lib ("/dir1", "/dir2");
```

On the command line:

```
    perl -Mlib=/dir1,/dir2
```

You can also [remove the directories from `@INC` via `no lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html#Deleting-directories-from-@INC).

5. You can directly manipulate `@INC` as a regular Perl array.

Note: Since `@INC` is used during the compilation phase, this must be done inside a `BEGIN {}` block, which precedes the `use MyModule` statement.

- Add directories to the beginning via `unshift @INC, $dir`.
- Add directories to the end via `push @INC, $dir`.
- Do anything else you can do with a Perl array.

Note: The directories are *unshifted* onto `@INC` in the order listed in this answer, e.g. default `@INC` is last in the list, preceded by `PERL5LIB`, preceded by `-I`, preceded by `use lib` and direct `@INC` manipulation, the latter two mixed in whichever order they are in Perl code.

#### References:

- [perldoc perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Perl-Modules)
- [perldoc lib](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html)
- [Perl Module Mechanics - a great guide containing practical HOW-TOs](http://world.std.com/%7Eswmcd/steven/perl/module_mechanics.html)
- [How do I 'use' a Perl module in a directory not in `@INC`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185114/how-do-i-use-a-perl-module-in-a-directory-not-in-inc)
- [Programming Perl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596000278) - chapter 31 part 13, ch 7.2.41
- [How does a Perl program know where to find the file containing Perl module it uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526520/how-does-a-perl-program-know-where-to-find-the-file-containing-perl-module-it-use)

There does not seem to be a comprehensive `@INC` FAQ-type post on Stack Overflow, so this question is intended as one.

#### When to use each approach?

- If the modules in a directory need to be used by many/all scripts on your site, especially run by multiple users, that directory should be included in the default `@INC` compiled into the Perl binary.
- If the modules in the directory will be used exclusively by a specific user for all the scripts that user runs (or if recompiling Perl is not an option for changing the default `@INC` in the previous use case), set the users' `PERL5LIB`, usually during user login.

*Note: Please be aware of the usual Unix environment variable pitfalls - e.g. in certain cases running the scripts as a particular user does not guarantee running them with that user's environment set up, e.g. via `su`.*

- If the modules in the directory need to be used only in specific circumstances (e.g. when the script(s) is executed in development/debug mode, you can either set `PERL5LIB` manually, or pass the `-I` option to perl.
- If the modules need to be used only for specific scripts, by *all* users using them, use `use lib`/`no lib` pragmas in the program itself. It also should be used when the directory to be searched needs to be dynamically determined during runtime - e.g. from the script's command line parameters or script's path (see the [FindBin](http://p3rl.org/FindBin) module for a very nice use case).
- If the directories in `@INC` need to be manipulated according to some complicated logic, either impossible or too unwieldy to implement by a combination of `use lib`/`no lib` pragmas, then use direct `@INC` manipulation inside a `BEGIN {}` block or inside a special purpose library designated for `@INC` manipulation, which must be used by your script(s) before any other modules are used.

An example of this is automatically switching between libraries in prod/uat/dev directories, with waterfall library pickup in prod if it's missing from dev and/or UAT (the last condition makes the standard "use lib + FindBin" solution fairly complicated.
A detailed illustration of this scenario is in [*How do I use beta Perl modules from beta Perl scripts?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474588/how-do-i-use-beta-perl-modules-from-beta-perl-scripts).

- An additional use case for directly manipulating `@INC` is to be able to add subroutine references or object references (yes, Virginia, `@INC` can contain custom Perl code and not just directory names, as explained in [*When is a subroutine reference in @INC called?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541119/when-is-a-subroutine-reference-in-inc-called)).

Comment: don't forget PERLOPT, where you can set -I. Also, things such as base.pm and local::lib use the things you've listed implicitly.

Comment: @brian - use::base uses it due to "require" underneath, IIRC. I'm not familiar with local::lib, will need to read more to understand what it is about

Comment: Also, to make this a really good answer, you need to tell people when they should use each one. Just giving them 10 options on how they could isn't very helpful. :)

Comment: P.S. Anyone, please feel free to edit the answer to include a second architecture-specific directory inclusion via -I/use lib. I planned to do so myself at a later time but need to get offline for now.

Comment: @brian - added PERLOPT. I feel like mentioning base.pm and other "when does @INC get used" items is more suited to the @INC/finding module files FAQ I posted and linked from here, so I put it there.

Comment: Your answering is looking pretty good. Just keep doing what you are doing. Writing is editing :)

Comment: I also added one more use case, the insertion of subroutine references into @INC

Comment: The output of perl -V depends on PERL5LIB and PERLLIB environment variables. I've modified the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Flimm - you're quite right. I approved the edit and added the example

Comment: Note: If you've made any modifications to `$PATH`, they will be stripped out by `env -i` -- so you may end up running a different `perl`.

Comment: Note that `PERL5LIB` and `use lib` also add arch dirs related to the specified dirs, while `-I` doesn't. That makes `-Mlib=...` much better than `-I ...`

Comment: @AndrewMcKinlay you may be even more right than you think - it may even strip out the whole `$PATH`! When I ran `env -i perl -V` I got `env: ‘perl’: No such file or directory`. I had to run `env -i /usr/bin/perl -V` (note specifying the full path to perl) to get the output expected.

Answer (score 21):

In addition to the locations listed above, the OS X version of Perl also has two more ways:

6. The /Library/Perl/x.xx/AppendToPath file.  Paths listed in this file are appended to @INC at runtime.
7. The /Library/Perl/x.xx/PrependToPath file.  Paths listed in this file are prepended to @INC at runtime.

Comment: When specifically are these files read during run time? When I look at the output of lsof, I have a rare case where the AppendToPath file is open for reading on fd 0 (STDIN), but in every other case I've tested, it's not there and I can't seem to make a toy example that duplicates that behavior. I'm curious why and when it's ever on STDIN. When will it be there?

Comment: I dug into why I have that handle open according to lsof.  Apparrently, at the top of the script that called the script that showed the open handle, there was a line of code that was closing STDIN (which was probably some misguided attempt to deal with some past issue).  But apparently, if you do that, child script processed will show STDIN open to that file on macOS. Don't know why yet though.

Answer (score 6):

As it was said already @INC is an array and you're free to add anything you want.

My CGI REST script looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
BEGIN {
    push @INC, 'fully_qualified_path_to_module_wiht_our_REST.pm';
}
use Modules::Rest;
gone(@_);
```

Subroutine gone is exported by Rest.pm.