# How can I include Perl modules with paths relative to the program?

Tags: perl, module, path

I have a Perl script which uses installed packages. One is a Perl package another one is Perl XS package.

Now I want to call this script but use not installed packages, but packages with the same name by path.

I used `perl -I /home/.../lib script.pl` but it doesn't work

How can I do it?

Comment: Look buddy, doesn't work is a strong statement. Does it sit on the couch all day? Is it making faces at you? Does it want more money? Is it sleeping with your girlfriend? Please be specific! :-)

Comment: so the problem is that you're trying to load a package of your own but a default package is being loaded instead?

Answer (score 5):

For various ways of affecting where your modules are loaded, please review this SO posting:

[How is Perl's @INC constructed? (aka What are all the ways of affecting where Perl modules are searched for?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-per)

Comment: I've tried every aproach  from the list/ but it doesn't help/ I still cannot use my own module(

Comment: You need to specify the exact package name for us to help in more detail - provide the `use xxx` line

Comment: Also, please specify the exact directory structure of the module code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) pragma to prepend directories to the path `perl` uses to find modules.

So, if there is a module named `Foo` installed in the default directories and a different version installed in `/home/cowens/perl5` you can say

```
use lib "/home/cowens/perl5";
use Foo;
```

and `perl` will find the version in `/home/cowens/perl5`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it's not my script, so I cannot modify it. I just can run it with options

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us a recursive listing of the directory where you're storing the modules you want to use? An `ls -R` could help us figure out if you have the right paths.

When you use the `-I` switch, you have to ensure you get the right path in there. If you use a module:

```
 use Some::Module;
```

Perl actually looks for:

```
 $lib/Some/Module.pm
```

The `$lib` is one of the directories in `@INC`. Another way to say that though, is that if the particular directory is not in `@INC`, Perl isn't going to look in it. This means that Perl won't automatically look in subdirectories for you

If your module is not at that location, Perl is not going to rummage around in that `$lib` to look for it. Your XS module is probably not stored like that. It might have a Perl version and archtype in the path, so you might find it in:

```
 $lib/5.10.1/darwin-2level/Some/Module.pm
```

You need to add those paths yourself if you are using `-I`.

However, you can load modules on the command line. It's much easier to use `lib`, which adds the extra directories for you:

```
 perl -Mlib=/path/to/lib ...
```

Comment: What are the pros & cons of -I and -Mlib

Comment: The benefits and risks depends what you are doing. One adds only what you say and one adds arch and version dirs to @INC. Whether that's good or bad depends on what you want.