# Running perl script from a shell script

Tags: perl, shell

I've written a shell script that does stuff on Centos64

At the end of this script, I run a perl script.

It works fine as root (I have installed the perl modules), but when I run it as a system user

I get the message:

`./UserActivityReport.sh
Can't locate MIME/Lite.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at /optreports/sendmailUAR.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/reports/sendmailUAR.pl line 3.`

As if the modules were not installed for the user...

I run the script with this command in my shell script:

```
/usr/bin/perl  /opt/reports/sendmailUAR.pl
```

Why is it not running?

NOTE: I cannot install the perl modules with the system user.

===
There you go:

```
perl -MMIME::Lite -MData::Dumper -e'print Dumper \%INC'
$VAR1 = {
          're.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/re.pm',
          'warnings/register.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/warnings/register.pm',
          'XSLoader.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/XSLoader.pm',
          'IO/Handle.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/IO/Handle.pm',
          'MIME/Types.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MIME/Types.pm',
          'SelectSaver.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/SelectSaver.pm',
          'IO/Seekable.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/IO/Seekable.pm',
          'warnings.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/warnings.pm',
          'File/Basename.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/File/Basename.pm',
          'Fcntl.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Fcntl.pm',
          'IO.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/IO.pm',
          'Symbol.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Symbol.pm',
          'bytes.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/bytes.pm',
          'MIME/Type.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MIME/Type.pm',
          'Carp.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Carp.pm',
          'MIME/Base64.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/MIME/Base64.pm',
          'Exporter/Heavy.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Exporter/Heavy.pm',
          'File/Spec/Unix.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/File/Spec/Unix.pm',
          'FileHandle.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/FileHandle.pm',
          'strict.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/strict.pm',
          'Exporter.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Exporter.pm',
          'vars.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/vars.pm',
          'MIME/Lite.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MIME/Lite.pm',
          'MIME/QuotedPrint.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/MIME/QuotedPrint.pm',
          'File/Spec.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/File/Spec.pm',
          'overload.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/overload.pm',
          'IO/File.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/IO/File.pm',
          'Mail/Address.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Mail/Address.pm',
          'Data/Dumper.pm' => '/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Data/Dumper.pm'
```

## };

Comment: run as root `perl -MMIME::Lite -MData::Dumper -e'print Dumper \%INC'` and post here the output.

Comment: The system user's @INC doesn't seem to have `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/` in it. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-per

Comment: The file is there alright ... What are its permissions?

Comment: @Lin how so? It's included in \@INC according to the error message.

Comment: [root~]# ls -l /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/
total 60
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4096 Sep 14 13:09 Date
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4096 Sep 14 13:09 Email
drwxr-x--- 4 root root 4096 Sep 14 13:10 Mail
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Sep 14 13:10 MIME
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Sep 15 06:30 OLE
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Sep 15 06:30 Parse
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Sep 14 13:10 Pod
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4096 Sep 15 06:30 Spreadsheet
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Sep 14 13:09 Time

-r--r--r-- 1 root root 6500 Aug 21 07:19 version.pm
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 9887 Aug 21 07:12 version.pod

Comment: My bad, it's in the error message. Was the MIME/Lite.pm module installed by CPAN? Are the permissions for that file readable by all?

Comment: @Rgonomike as root, try `chmod a+r -R /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MIME`

Comment: Yes, it's been install with CPAN:
[cipadmin@]$ locate Lite.pm
/home/cipadmin/.cpan/build/MIME-Lite-3.027/blib/lib/MIME/Lite.pm
/home/cipadmin/.cpan/build/MIME-Lite-3.027/lib/MIME/Lite.pm

Comment: Isn't it possible that inside my shell sript i need to run the perl script with some Options?

Answer (score 2):

In one of the comments, you have posted a directory listing like this:

```
[root~]# ls -l /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/
total 60
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4096 Sep 14 13:09 Date
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4096 Sep 14 13:09 Email
drwxr-x--- 4 root root 4096 Sep 14 13:10 Mail
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Sep 14 13:10 MIME
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Sep 15 06:30 OLE
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Sep 15 06:30 Parse
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Sep 14 13:10 Pod
drwxr-x--- 3 root root 4096 Sep 15 06:30 Spreadsheet
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 Sep 14 13:09 Time
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 6500 Aug 21 07:19 version.pm
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 9887 Aug 21 07:12 version.pod
```

It should be fairly evident that users other than `root` do not have access to these files.  You should probably do more thorough audit by looping over all of `@INC` and changing permissions as necessary, but for a start, `find /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 -type d -exec chmod a+rx {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting root's umask is such that files are not world readable by default.

```
find /usr/lib/perl5 -not -perm -o=r
```

Anything files listed are not world readable (and probably should be). You can fix it this way

```
find /usr/lib/perl5 -not -perm -o=r -exec chmod o+r {} +
```

If you wish to make all files matched with the first command readable by everyone.

Answer (score 1):

`MIME::Lite` is at `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MIME/Lite.pm` and `/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8` is in system's `@INC` path.

As user `system` check that you can read that file:

```
cat /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/MIME/Lite.pm
```

If you get an error doing so check the permissions of the file and the parent directories.

Otherwise, run the script as `system` with `strace` and see why it is failing to find the module file.

Comment: Alright so I did a chmod 755 on /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 and it solved the issue :)