# add Perl Modules' Directory to include path using .htaccess for CGI scripts

Tags: perl, .htaccess, module, cgi, include-path

I've used Cpanel to install per modules on my host server running lightspeed.
It gave an "Installation Successful" message too.

But it shows:

**Location of Your Perl Module(s)**
Path: /home/username/perl

**Using Your Perl Module(s):**
You will need to add /home/username/perl to the include path.

Is it possible to add it using only .htaccess? Because it's my only access to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible using the SetEnv directive. Try putting this in your .htaccess:

```
SetEnv PERL5LIB /home/username/perl
```

If you want to add more than one path, separate them with `:`, like this:

```
SetEnv PERL5LIB /home/username/perl:/some/other/path
```

You can (of course) also use this to set other environment variables.

Another option would be adding it to the include path from inside Perl itself. You will have to add the line `use lib "/home/username/perl";` to the CGI script(s), somewhere before it loads the module(s) installed there.

Answer (score 2):

Since you installed these modules manually, i recommend using either `use lib` or pushing the directory to INC array. Look at this [How is Perl's @INC constructed? (aka What are all the ways of affecting where Perl modules are searched for?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe)

So, you can use either of the below techniques

**use lib**

```
use lib /home/username/perl
```

**Modifying INC array**

To add directories to the beginning

```
unshift @INC, /home/username/perl
```

To add directories to the end

```
push @INC, /home/username/perl
```

I also recommend moving the modules to a directory relative to your cgi-bin and using [FindBin](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/lib/FindBin.pm) and add the directory to INC