# Does the otherlibdirs Configure option rewrite or just modify @INC?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm a perl noob and I have a very basic question regarding the `@INC` post: [How is Perl's @INC constructed? (aka What are all the ways of affecting where Perl modules are searched for?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe)

Does the "otherlibdirs" Configure option completely rewrite the directories that are part of `@INC`, or merely add another directory? It's not clear to me from that answer what it does, and I don't want to screw up the whole `@INC` path.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perusing source of the Perl [Configure script](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/blead/Configure), we find the following usage information:

```
case "$otherlibdirs" in
''|' ') dflt='none' ;;
*)  dflt="$otherlibdirs" ;;
esac
$cat <<EOM
Enter a colon-separated set of extra paths to include in perl's @INC
search path, or enter 'none' for no extra paths.

EOM
```

So if you compile Perl with something like

```
    Configure -Dotherlibdirs=/usr/foo/bar:/usr/foo/bar/baz
```

Then the directories `/usr/foo/bar` and `/usr/foo/bar/baz` will be appended to the normal `@INC` built-in to the `perl` binary.

Comment: And now my complete command-line incompetence comes back into play: When I try to run that command, it's telling me "Configure: command not found".

Comment: @user1088336 Is your question how to change `@INC` inside a perl script? Because this is something quite more fundamental.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I want to change the default INC. Right now, the directory where CPAN is building new perl modules is not included in the default INC. If I'm understanding the situation correctly, I could either tell every script where to find the modules it needs, or I could update the default INC statement so that it knows where to look to find the modules built by CPAN. Am I thinking about this correctly?