# Perl Module usage

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to create my own Perl module in /usr/local/lib/perl

I have the environmental variable PERL5LIB set:

```
$ env | grep PERL
PERL5LIB=/usr/local/lib/perl
```

If I create a module: $PERL5LIB/My/ModuleTest.pm

```
$ ./test.pl 
Can't locate object method "new" via package "My::ModuleTest" (perhaps you forgot to load "My::ModuleTest"?) at ./test.pl line 8.
```

test.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use My::ModuleTest;

my $test = new My::ModuleTest;
print $test->check;
```

ModuleTest.pm:

```
package ModuleTest;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new {
        my $class = shift;
        my ($opts)= @_;
        my $self = {};
        $self->{test} = "Hello World";

        return bless $self, $class;
}
sub check {
        my $self = shift;
        my ($opts) = @_;

        return $self->{test};
}
1;
```

I want to use the $PERL5LIB as the library path for my modules to segregate them from the installation directory.

Perl @INC:

```
$ perl -le 'print foreach @INC'
/usr/local/lib/perl
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8
.
```

Comment: Seems odd:    my $test = new My::ModuleTest;

Comment: Oyvind: It works, though most Perl fanatics will advise you to use `my $test = My::ModuleTest->new();` to avoid certain pitfalls.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `package My::ModuleTest;` in your file `ModuleTest.pm` - you should use the full name.

Comment: Thanks. Great question btw - all the necessary info was there, you've showed everything you tried, allowed us to recreate the situation, perfectly formatted... you deserve fast answers :]

Comment: One last question, is it necessary for root to have the PERL5LIB env variable or will it look to /usr/local/lib/perl as part of its path?

Comment: @user196096: great question - that's why [someone else on stackoverflow already asked it (link)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe), and it was answered too! :]

Answer (score 3):

Change the first line of your module from

```
package ModuleTest;
```

to

```
package My::ModuleTest;
```