# Regarding BEGIN{ Push ....} in Perl

Tags: perl

In some perl programs, I see they begin with

```
BEGIN
{
push(@INC, '/home/usr1/Modules');
}
```

I would like to know what does this part intend to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is Perl's @INC constructed? (aka What are all the ways of affecting where Perl modules are searched for?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ensures that any perl modules which are contained in the directory `/home/usr1/Modules` will be available for usage.

When one types `use ModuleName`, Perl will search every directory in `@INC` for the file `ModuleName.pm`.

Comment: but why not simply:   use lib '/my/path' ? Available in core since 1995.. (http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html)

Comment: yeah, that'd work too.  Honestly, all my modules are in place by setting the environment variable `PERL5LIB` in my bash profile, so neither of these things are truly necessary

Comment: @asf107, `PERL5LIB` is ignored in taint mode, which may never be an issue for you but can be a issue in secure environments.