# Running Perl Script as CGI Script vs from cmd line

Tags: perl, cgi

I am trying to run a Perl script as a CGI script. When I run the perl script from cmd line, it runs perfectly well, but it shows the following error when I run it from my browser.

```
Storable object version 1.012 does not match $Storable::VERSION 1.010 at
C:/Perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 225.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Perl/site/lib/AsiaXMLUtils.pm line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Perl/site/lib/AsiaXMLUtils.pm line 20
```

The perl script concerned has basically been designed to queue some job to a remote software.
In case it rings a bell, Line 20 in the mentioned file is :

```
use Storable qw(&retrieve &store);
```

Here are the things I have done :

1. I have checked the following pages on [how to troubleshoot your CGI
   script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script/2165040#2165040) but haven't got around the problem.
2. I have checked that the perl versions are the same for my PC as well
   that used for the software I am sending the script too. I guess had
   that been a problem, I wouldn't have been able to run the script
   from the commnad line either.
3. I have run a simple Perl CGI (hello world) script using the same basic html code, so I guess that means I am not putting the cgi files (or accessing them) at the wrong places.

I am running a deadline for finishing this task, and thought should ask what approach I should take to solve such a problem. I am new to Perl. Any cues to what I should read to get around the problem will be greatly appreciated. I cannot share the code anyways, since much of it is proprietary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storable is an XS module, which means that it has both C code in Storable.dll (or Storable.so on Unix) and Perl code in Storable.pm.  That error indicates that the version of Storable.dll ("Storable object version 1.012") does not match Storable.pm ("$Storable::VERSION 1.010").  If you can run the script from the command line, that means that your webserver is either using a different version of Perl, or `@INC` is different, or possibly you have an extra Storable.dll in your webserver's directory.

Comment: Thank you! That was great insight!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `nstore` instead of `store`. This way, your file will be crossplatform. 
Also, try to reinstall the Store module.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I was able to solve the issue, which btw wouldn't have been possible without the valuable inputs of *Miguel Prz* and *cjm*.

1. Regarding the Storable Module : After reading both the answers, I noticed that my pc had two versions of
   Perl. I removed one of them. This got me around the "Storable object
   version 1.012 does not match $Storable::VERSION" error. Sounds pretty lame, I know. But I thought I should let you know anyways. But then
   I ran into another set of problems. This :

   **Can't locate
       AJE/Constants.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/lib
       C:/Perl/site/lib .)**
2. From comparing with the @INC of the perl environment from the
           command line (for which I found [**this SO post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe) very useful), I
           noticed that the @INC that my web server was using (consisting of only 2 directories as shown above) did not include
           many of the directories in the @INC of the command line perl environment. This is where *cjm*'s words came back to me! I then used [**use lib**](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) to add those files in my
       perl script and that solved the problem!

Thank you for all the help!