# Getting the full set of installed Perl modules

Tags: linux, perl

While recursing through all of the `@INC` directories will give you the modules that "Perl knows about", what's the cleanest way to find *all* of the modules that have been built on a (Linux) system?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq3.html#How-do-I-find-which-modules-are-installed-on-my-system%3f)? Try `cpan -l`

Comment: All of the modules that have been built? Does that include modules built by other users? Modules installed with perlbrew?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, this is the crux of the problem. I tried to keep my question focused, but in hindsight did not adequately address the issue: I am a developer with only adequate sa skills that has been tasked to unravel a system that had been driven to the absolute height-of-cruft. There modules everywhere, a paucity of documentation, and a gaping void of SOPs. I ended up having to dump everything scarcely perl-related into a tarball and will be tracing code for the foreseeable future. A classic throw-it-all-out-and-start-from-scratch-is-faster situation...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a Perl FAQ, i.e. *How do I find which modules are installed on my system?*, you can find the answer for this question by `perldoc -q installed` or `perldoc perlfaq3` and then search for 'installed'.

Here is a summary of the answer in 'perlfaq3.pod' to this question and some notes about the answer itself according to my test of it:

1. use `cpan` on command line:

   ```
   cpan -l
   ```

   Note: You may need to install extra package to use this command, for example, you need to install 'perl-CPAN' in Fedora 19.
2. use `ExtUtils::Installed` in a Perl script:

   ```
   use ExtUtils::Installed;

   my $inst    = ExtUtils::Installed->new();
   my @modules = $inst->modules();
   ```

   Note: this may not be able to list all the modules installed by your package management system.
3. use `File::Find::Rule` to find all the module files:

   ```
   use File::Find::Rule;

   my @files = File::Find::Rule->
           extras({follow => 1})->
           file()->
           name( '*.pm' )->
           in( @INC )
           ;
   ```

   Note: this is not a standard module, you may need to install it first.
4. use `File::Find` to find all the module files:

   ```
   use File::Find;
   my @files;

   find(
       {
           wanted => sub {
               push @files, $File::Find::fullname
                   if -f $File::Find::fullname && /\.pm$/
           },
           follow => 1,
           follow_skip => 2,
       },
       @INC
   );

   print join "\n", @files;
   ```
5. if you know the module name and just want to check whether it exists in your system, you can use the following commands:

   ```
   perldoc Module::Name
   ```

   or

   ```
   perl -MModule::Name -e1
   ```

The following links may also be helpful:

- [How is Perl's @INC constructed? (aka What are all the ways of affecting where Perl modules are searched for?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe)
- [How do I add a directory to my include path (@INC) at runtime?](http://search.cpan.org/~dapm/perl-5.14.4/pod/perlfaq8.pod#How_do_I_add_a_directory_to_my_include_path_(@INC)_at_runtime?)

Comment: This answer would be much better if you summarized the contents of the FAQ instead of just saying "look here."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Updated, I hope this one is good enough :-)

Comment: Now *that* is a quality answer :)

Comment: @leeduhem: <at>ThisSuitIsBlackNot is exactly right--that _is_ a quality answer. Your example glued my blotchy direction together. Thanks for helping a brotha out.