# How to print filtered output list of an external command in Perl?

Tags: strawberry-perl, perl

I'm learning Perl. As an exersize, I try to print all installed Mojolicious modules. I'm using Strawberry Perl and don't have `grep` installed.

My naive try is:

```
perl -wE "for (sort `cpan -l`) { chomp; say if index($_, 'Mojo') == 0; };"
```

I found out that `cpan -l` returns a list. I expected a string, but never mind. I `sort` the returned list, `chomp` each record and `say` the ones that start with 'Mojo'.

It rather works, but prints each line twice:

```
Mojolicious::Sessions   undef
Mojolicious::Sessions   undef
Mojolicious::Static     undef
Mojolicious::Static     undef
Mojolicious::Types      undef
Mojolicious::Types      undef
Mojolicious::Validator  undef
Mojolicious::Validator  undef
Mojolicious::Validator::Validation      undef
Mojolicious::Validator::Validation      undef
```

What it is wrong that prints each record twice?

**Edit:**

I run the code under Cent OS. It looks like it works fine but have two versions of the libs installed.

```
perl -we 'for (sort `cpan -l`) { chomp; print $_, "\n" if index($_, "JSON") == 0; };'

JSON::PP        4.02
JSON::PP        4.04
JSON::PP::Boolean       4.02
JSON::PP::Boolean       4.04
```

**Edit 2:**

As recommended by @zdim, I checked the file paths of the installed modules. It appeared that there are doubled installations:

```
whichpm -a Mojolicious
C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\Mojolicious.pm
C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\Mojolicious.pm


whichpm -v Mojolicious
whichpm: WARNING: DUPLICATE module files found for 'Mojolicious':
  C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\Mojolicious.pm
Mojolicious     8.22    (non-core)      C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\Mojolicious.pm
```

It looks like the question was wrong.

A possible reason for the duplicated installation can be inproper modules update. After installing Strawbery I used the following command:

```
cpan-outdated -p | cpanm
```

Thank you guys for the help. It looks like it was the wrong question. I accept the given answer and will open a new 'better' question.

Comment: You do have Perl's `grep` installed: `perl -e "print sort grep/^Mojo/,qx(cpan -l)"`

Comment: @mob, you are right. I meant `grep` command in the console.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that there are two versions of each module installed. `cpan -l` show sth eversion string as `undef` on some reason.

Comment: Print exact file locations for each to see what that doubling is about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what `cpan` does and its man page is sprawling for me. Could it be listing modules from two Perl versions? Or there are indeed two versions of modules installed?

Here is another option, with core [ExtUtils::Installed](https://perldoc.perl.org/ExtUtils/Installed.html)

```
perl -MExtUtils::Installed -MList::Util=max -wE'
    $obj = ExtUtils::Installed->new; 
    @mods = sort $obj->modules; 
    $max_len = max map { length } @mods; 
    printf("%-${max_len}s -- %s\n", $_, $obj->version($_)) for @mods'
```

This prints all of them.  To see just the ones starting with `Mojo` change the last line to

```
/^Mojo/ and printf("%-${max_len}s -- %s\n", $_, $obj->version($_)) for @mods'
```

The `/^Mojo/` is a regex that tests `$_` (by default) for whether it starts with (`^` anchor) the literal string `Mojo`. This is I think clearer than using `index`, and is idiomatic (more readily understood).

But [printf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) has for the field width the length of the longest module name, found before filtering, which is likely too wide for the filtered list.  So for nicer output you can first filter with [grep](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)

```
my @mods_filtered = sort grep { /^Mojo/ } $obj->modules; 
my $max_len = max map { length } @mods_filtered; 
printf("%-${max_len}s -- %s\n", $_, $obj->version($_)) for @mods_filtered;
```

All this should be in a small utility script; the one-liner above is for copy-paste testing.

See documentation for details on what this module does.

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21198713/4653379), with code for another option -- to search for files directly.

Comment: @MiroslavPopov Yeah, regex is useful; can be really clean and easy to write. (And it can be overly complex and powerful as well.)  That said, the good old `index` seems undervalued in Perl -- even though there are indeed usually other, easier-to-code ways in such a rich language. But  I wouldn't be surprised if what you did was much faster than starting a regex engine (but I don't know that, it should be benchmarked).  That would of course only matter if it's done a lot, but these kinds of checks often are.

Comment: Found duplicated installations. Checked via `whichpm`:

    `C:\Users\info\OneDrive\Documents>whichpm -a Mojolicious`
    `C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\Mojolicious.pm`
    `C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\Mojolicious.pm`

    `C:\Users\info\OneDrive\Documents>whichpm -v Mojolicious`
`whichpm: WARNING: DUPLICATE module files found for 'Mojolicious':`
    `C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib\Mojolicious.pm
Mojolicious     8.22    (non-core)      C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\Mojolicious.pm`

Comment: can I change the question to "how to deal with duplicated modules installation? Is it allowed in SO?

Comment: @MiroslavPopov  (Short answer: Your question and you can change it any way you like; however, it is not a good idea to actually _change_ it, its substance. Once people have seen it, and specially once there are answers, then it's baked.   The edit is great -- you updated meaningfully and didn't change the question.)  It is common to see things differently after pondering over it and seeing comments and answers; it's a part of the process, articulating our questions better.  Normal stuff, and it's that way with SO as well -- and then you ask another question.

Comment: @MiroslavPopov  "_Found duplicated installations_"  --- great!  And good that you looked, because that doesn't seem right, and good that you ask (new question) about it. Also of general interest I think, as I suspect it happens often.