# errors and strange behaviour when compiling perl script

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl2exe

I've a perl script and when I compile it with  perl2exe it gives the following message:

> `Can't locate unicore/Heavy.pl in @INC (@INC contains: PERL2EXE_STORAGE
>   c:\tools\hunalign\scripts\sentence_splitter
>   C:\Users\EURIDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp/p2xtmp-5936) at
>   PERL2EXE_STORAGE/utf8_heavy.pl line 176.`

I have the file in the unicore module, so I don't know what the problem is.
However, I could temporarily overcome this by inserting this line:

```
#perl2exe_include "unicore/Heavy.pl";
```

now it compiles without error, but the exe works a bit different than the original exe compiled by the maker of the program. (It's a parser that segments sentences, and my exe doesn't segment at full stops). May it be due to a limitation of the free version of perl2exe? Any ideas?

**CODE** (both for original build and my own)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Encode::Unicode;
use utf8;
#perl2exe_include "unicore/Heavy.pl";

# Based on Preprocessor written by Philipp Koehn

binmode(STDIN, ":utf8");
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
binmode(STDERR, ":utf8");

use FindBin qw($Bin);
use strict;

my $mydir = "$Bin/nonbreaking_prefixes";

my %NONBREAKING_PREFIX = ();
my $language = "en";
my $QUIET = 0;
my $HELP = 0;

while (@ARGV) {
    $_ = shift;
    /^-l$/ && ($language = shift, next);
    /^-q$/ && ($QUIET = 1, next);
    /^-h$/ && ($HELP = 1, next);
}

if ($HELP) {
    print "Usage ./split-sentences.perl (-l [en|de|...]) < textfile > splitfile\n";
    exit;
}
if (!$QUIET) {
    print STDERR "Sentence Splitter v3\n";
    print STDERR "Language: $language\n";
}

my $prefixfile = "$mydir/nonbreaking_prefix.$language";

#default back to English if we don't have a language-specific prefix file
if (!(-e $prefixfile)) {
    $prefixfile = "$mydir/nonbreaking_prefix.en";
    print STDERR "WARNING: No known abbreviations for language '$language', attempting fall-back to English version...\n";
    die ("ERROR: No abbreviations files found in $mydir\n") unless (-e $prefixfile);
}

if (-e "$prefixfile") {
    open(PREFIX, "<:utf8", "$prefixfile");
    while (<PREFIX>) {
        my $item = $_;
        chomp($item);
        if (($item) && (substr($item,0,1) ne "#")) {
            if ($item =~ /(.*)[\s]+(\#NUMERIC_ONLY\#)/) {
                $NONBREAKING_PREFIX{$1} = 2;
            } else {
                $NONBREAKING_PREFIX{$item} = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    close(PREFIX);
}

##loop text, add lines together until we get a blank line or a <p>
my $text = "";
while(<STDIN>) {
    chop;
    if (/^<.+>$/ || /^\s*$/) {
        #time to process this block, we've hit a blank or <p>
        &do_it_for($text,$_);
        print "<P>\n" if (/^\s*$/ && $text); ##if we have text followed by <P>
        $text = "";
    }
    else {
        #append the text, with a space
        $text .= $_. " ";
    }
}
#do the leftover text
&do_it_for($text,"") if $text;


sub do_it_for {
    my($text,$markup) = @_;
    print &preprocess($text) if $text;
    print "$markup\n" if ($markup =~ /^<.+>$/);
    #chop($text);
}

sub preprocess {
    # clean up spaces at head and tail of each line as well as any double-spacing
    $text =~ s/ +/ /g;
    $text =~ s/\n /\n/g;
    $text =~ s/ \n/\n/g;
    $text =~ s/^ //g;
    $text =~ s/ $//g;

    #this is one paragraph
    my($text) = @_;

    #####add sentence breaks as needed#####

    #non-period end of sentence markers (?!) followed by sentence starters.
    $text =~ s/([?!]) +([\'\"\(\[\¿\¡\p{IsPi}]*[\p{IsUpper}])/$1\n$2/g;

    #multi-dots followed by sentence starters
    $text =~ s/(\.[\.]+) +([\'\"\(\[\¿\¡\p{IsPi}]*[\p{IsUpper}])/$1\n$2/g;

    # add breaks for sentences that end with some sort of punctuation inside a quote or parenthetical and are followed by a possible sentence starter punctuation and upper case
    $text =~ s/([?!\.][\ ]*[\'\"\)\]\p{IsPf}]+) +([\'\"\(\[\¿\¡\p{IsPi}]*[\ ]*[\p{IsUpper}])/$1\n$2/g;

    # add breaks for sentences that end with some sort of punctuation are followed by a sentence starter punctuation and upper case
    $text =~ s/([?!\.]) +([\'\"\(\[\¿\¡\p{IsPi}]+[\ ]*[\p{IsUpper}])/$1\n$2/g;

    # special punctuation cases are covered. Check all remaining periods.
    my $word;
    my $i;
    my @words = split(/ /,$text);
    $text = "";
    for ($i=0;$i<(scalar(@words)-1);$i++) {
        if ($words[$i] =~ /([\p{IsAlnum}\.\-]*)([\'\"\)\]\%\p{IsPf}]*)(\.+)$/) {
            #check if $1 is a known honorific and $2 is empty, never break
            my $prefix = $1;
            my $starting_punct = $2;
            if($prefix && $NONBREAKING_PREFIX{$prefix} && $NONBREAKING_PREFIX{$prefix} == 1 && !$starting_punct) {
                #not breaking;
            } elsif ($words[$i] =~ /(\.)[\p{IsUpper}\-]+(\.+)$/) {
                #not breaking - upper case acronym  
            } elsif($words[$i+1] =~ /^([ ]*[\'\"\(\[\¿\¡\p{IsPi}]*[ ]*[\p{IsUpper}0-9])/) {
                #the next word has a bunch of initial quotes, maybe a space, then either upper case or a number
                $words[$i] = $words[$i]."\n" unless ($prefix && $NONBREAKING_PREFIX{$prefix} && $NONBREAKING_PREFIX{$prefix} == 2 && !$starting_punct && ($words[$i+1] =~ /^[0-9]+/));
                #we always add a return for these unless we have a numeric non-breaker and a number start
            }

        }
        $text = $text.$words[$i]." ";
    }

    #we stopped one token from the end to allow for easy look-ahead. Append it now.
    $text = $text.$words[$i];

    # clean up spaces at head and tail of each line as well as any double-spacing
    $text =~ s/ +/ /g;
    $text =~ s/\n /\n/g;
    $text =~ s/ \n/\n/g;
    $text =~ s/^ //g;
    $text =~ s/ $//g;

    #add trailing break
    $text .= "\n" unless $text =~ /\n$/;

    return $text;

}
```

Comment: Might you have more than one copy of Heavy.pl on your system?

Answer (score 2):

Can't locate XYZ in @INC means Perl is unable to find XYZ module in @INC. This means either the module is not installed or its path is not searchable, you need to add the path to your module to @INC.

See the below threads:

1. [How is Perl's @INC constructed? (aka What are all the ways of affecting where Perl modules are searched for?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe)
2. [How to change @INC to find Perl modules in non-standard locations](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations)

Using `#perl2exe_include "unicore/Heavy.pl";` solves the issue because it specifies the path of module hence Perl knows where to look. (perl2exe adds the module to the executable).

> exe works a bit different than the original exe

You should share your code else how'd we know what was original and what is current?

Comment: It's long and wasn't sure it won't flood all over.. see my post updated, thanks!