# I want to create a word count module and I want to reuse it further

Tags: perl

I want to create a module in Perl. The below code is not working properly. I want to create a word count module and I want to reuse it further. Can anyone help me out to create this module? This is my first attempt to create a module so kindly help me out.

```
package My::count

use Exporter qw(import);
our @Export_ok = qw(line_count);

sub line_count {
  my $line = @_;
  return $line;
}
```

I saved the above code in `count.pm`

```
use My::count qw(line_count);

open INPUT, "<filename.txt";
$line++;
print line count is $line \n";
```

I saved the above script in `.pi` extension.

This code is showing error when I run it on an Ubuntu platform. Kindly help me to fix this errors.

Comment: What's the error the code is showing?

Comment: Can't locate My/count.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at g.pl line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at g.pl line 1.

Comment: [This](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-create-a-perl-module-for-code-reuse) is a pretty good article that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Perl scripts are stored with `.pl` extension. As you say `use My::count qw(line_count);` Perl tries to search the modules from the directories stored in `@INC` variable. You can run it with the `-I` flag to specify the directory to search the custom packages. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe?lq=1) question for more info.

Answer (score 0):

By convention Perl packages usually have a capitalized first letter, so `My::count` is more in keeping with convention if you call it `package My::Count;`.  Typically lower-cased module names are reserved for pragmas such as 'strict' and 'warnings'.  So go ahead and change the name to `My::Count`.

Next, save the module in a path such as `lib/My/Count.pm`.  `lib` is by convention as well.

Then you have to tell your script where to find package `My::Count`.

Let's assume you're storing your module and your executable like this:

```
~/project/lib/My/Count.pm
~/project/bin/count.pl
```

Notice I also used a .pl extension for the executable.  This is another convention.  Often on Unix-like systems people omit the `.pl` extension altogether.

Finally, in your `count.pl` file you need to tell `perl` where to find the library.  Often that is done like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use FindBin qw($Bin);
use lib "$Bin/../lib";

use My::Count 'line_count';

# The rest goes here...
```

As you can see, we're using `FindBin` to locate where the executable is stored, and then telling `perl` that it should look (among other places) in the `lib` folder stored in a relative location to the executable.

Naturally, as this is Perl, this is not the only way to do it.  But it's one common idiom.

Comment: Can't locate My/Count.pm in @INC (you may need to install the My::Count module) (@INC contains: /home/ngs6/adi2/../lib /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at count.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at count.pl line 6.

how to fix this problem sir, kindly help me to fix this problem !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `count.pm` file into a directory called `My`. So you have the following.

```
./count.pl
./My/count.pm
```

Comment: if i run 2nd command" bash: ./My/count.pm: permission denied" like this out put is coming , kindly fix this plz

Comment: I wasn't telling you to run those as commands. I was showing you where to put the files. Look, why don't you just pay a programmer to write this for you?