# What does perl -I means

Tags: perl

I see this a lot in bash scripts and I cannot see this in the manual and other sites.

What does the -I in running a perl script mean?

It is run like this:

```
perl -I$prod_dir $prod_dir/script.pl <parameter1> <parameter2>
```

Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> -Idirectory
>
> Directories specified by -I are prepended to the search path for modules (@INC ).

Source: [perlrun documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

It means `perl` will include the modules available under specified directory following `-I` which is `$prod_dir` in your case.

By default Perl picks up modules from `@INC`. If you want to use a module which is not available in `@INC` then you can specify the directory using `-I`. This specified directory will be appended to `@INC` at run time.

Also read:

- [How is Perl's @INC constructed? (aka What are all the ways of affecting where Perl modules are searched for?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe)
- [How to change @INC to find Perl modules in non-standard locations](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations)