# Inheritance in perl is showing a error in my case

Tags: perl, inheritance, perl-module

I have two perl modules onee.pm and two.pm and one perl script.Following is one.pm

```
 package one;
sub foo
{
 print "this is one\n";
}
sub goo
{
 print "This is two\n";
}
1;
```

two.pm

```
package two;
use one;
@ISA=(one);
sub hoo
{
  print "this is three \n";
}
1;
```

inherit.pl

```
use two;
foo();
```

when i execute inherit.pl am getting following error.

```
 Undefined subroutine &main::foo called at inherit.pl line 2.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Perl's @INC constructed? (aka What are all the ways of affecting where Perl modules are searched for?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe)

Comment: @dubes I disagree with that assessment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance works on objects. What you're trying to do is importing, not inherit. I've outlined both an example of inheritance and importing below.

Inheritance:

`One.pm`:

```
package One;

sub foo {
    print "this is one\n";
}
1;
```

`Two.pm`:

```
package Two;

# Note the use of 'use base ...;'. That means that we'll inherit 
# all functions from the package we're calling it on. We can override
# any inherited methods by re-defining them if we need/want

use base 'One';

sub new {
    return bless {}, shift;
}
1;
```

`inherit.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Two;

my $obj = Two->new;
$obj->foo;
```

Importing:

`One.pm`:

```
package One;

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(foo); # allow user to import the 'foo' function if desired

sub foo {
    print "this is one\n";
}
1;
```

`Two.pm`:

```
package Two;
use One qw(foo); # import foo() from One

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(foo); # re-export it so users of Two can import it

1;
```

`import.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Two qw(foo);

foo();
```

Note that in the next Perl Release (5.26.0), `@INC` will not include the current working directory by default, so to `use One;` or `use Two;` if those module files are in the local directory, you'll have to add `use lib '.';` or `unshift @INC, '.';` or the like.

Comment: Thank you for explaining  inheritance and import

Answer (score 3):

The inheritance has nothing to do with it. You are not exporting anything, so the `foo` subroutine is not in your script's namespace.

In fact you are also mixing up object oriented concepts (the inheritance) and classic Perl modules. If you have a non oop module, you can have exporter and bring subs into your script. If you have a class, you can inherit from another class. But then you would typically not export anything.

Now if you wanted to use `two` to import something from `one`, essentially building something like a collection of common functions, you would need to use Exporter in `one`, then `use one` in `two`, and then use Exporter in `two` to export the functions imported from `one`.

Sounds complicated? It does because it is complicated. There is no real benefit from doing that unless saving one line of `use one` in your script.