# Perl package file Can't locate

Tags: perl

I have integrate sample function in perl. Everything working fine but i am not able to connect Perl module package file(.pm)

Please review below code

sample.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use Sample;
print Sample->test_function();
```

Sample.pm

```
 package Sample;

  sub  test_function
  {

  return 'Welcome';

  }
```

Once after run the sample.pl file. It's return the error **"Can't locate Sample.pm "** but the package file availale in same folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of the issue is installed perl module location could not found . add the below line your sample.pl file

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 use Cwd qw( abs_path );
 use File::Basename qw( dirname );
 use lib dirname(abs_path($0));


 use Sample;
 print Sample->test_function();
```

Comment: See also [FindBin](https://metacpan.org/pod/FindBin)

Comment: [No, not FindBin](http://web.archive.org/web/2018/http://use.perl.org/~Aristotle/journal/33995)

Comment: @daxim, That issue was fixed in 1.51

Comment: Cool, for those (like me) who missed that change: http://p3rl.org/perl5160delta#Updated-Modules-and-Pragmata

Comment: Note that since FindBin is not dual-life, it is broken forever on older Perls. Just another reason I avoid it and use [lib::relative](https://metacpan.org/pod/lib::relative).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your `Sample.pm` file must finish returning a true value. The common way to do that is appending `1;` and the end of that file.

```
package Sample;
use strict;
use warnings;
sub  test_function {
   return 'Welcome';
}
1;
```

After Perl 5.26, current directory was removed from `@INC`. There are several ways to deal with this. For example, you can use the `-I` option when running the script:

```
perl -I. sample.pl
```

For a more deeper lecture on how to deal with `@INC`, please [read this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe).

Comment: It doesn't make sense to force the script's invoker to provide that information.

Comment: `-I ...` doesn't add arch dirs, so it doesn't always work. `-Mlib=...` should be used instead to get build-specific components.