# Perl throws "Can't locate Config/YAML.pm in @INC"

Tags: perl, ubuntu, apt

I'm getting `Can't locate Config/YAML.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Config::YAML module)` while running a perl script.

> Can't locate Config/YAML.pm in @INC (you may need to install the
>   Config::YAML module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl
>   /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5
>   /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18
>   /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at myperlscript line 8. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at myperlscript line 8.

Line 8 of the script shows `use Config::YAML;`.
I'm using Ubuntu and have installed the `libdata-yaml-perl` and `libyaml-perl` packages, but still am getting the same error. What else is needed?

Answer (score 6):

`Config::YAML` requires a different package. Install the [`libconfig-yaml-perl`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/libconfig-yaml-perl) package and the problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 22.04, I was only missing `libyaml-tiny-perl` and `libfile-homedir-perl`:

```
sudo apt-get install libyaml-tiny-perl libfile-homedir-perl
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, something is missing in `@INC`. If you do have the module installed (`perldoc -l YAML::Tiny` for example) it might be installed in a location that is not added to `@INC` (see [How is Perl's @INC constructed? (aka What are all the ways of affecting where Perl modules are searched for?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526804/how-is-perls-inc-constructed-aka-what-are-all-the-ways-of-affecting-where-pe) for how it's constructed).

That means that there could be something wrong with environment variables: if for example `PERL5LIB` is not set (or not set correctly), it could also cause this error.

For example, if Perl is installed in `/home/myusername/perl5`, setting `PERL5LIB="/home/myusername/perl5/lib/perl5"` can fix this (e.g. in your `~/.profile`, don't forget to log out and in).

For reference, here is what my Perl installation had autogenerated:

```
PATH="/home/myusername/perl5/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}"; export PATH;
PERL5LIB="/home/myusername/perl5/lib/perl5${PERL5LIB:+:${PERL5LIB}}"; export PERL5LIB;
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/home/myusername/perl5${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT:+:${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT}}"; export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT;
PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base \"/home/myusername/perl5\""; export PERL_MB_OPT;
PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=/home/myusername/perl5"; export PERL_MM_OPT;
```